# How to access laravel API with VUE JS?

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js

so i want to use mylogin api but its not working,it keep push the route to dashboard even the email and the password incorrect
here is my code

```
export default {
data(){
  return{
    form: {
    email: null,
    password: null
  },
    user: {},
    error: false
  }
},
methods: {
  login() {
    this.user.append("email", this.form.email);
        this.user.append("password", this.form.password);
        this.axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login', this.user).then(response => {
          localStorage.setItem("Name", response.data.first_name);
          this.$router.push('/userDashboard/Dashboard')
        });
  
  },
  register() {
    this.$router.push('/RegisterPage')
  }
},}
```

my laravel route api

```
Route::post('/login', 'UserController@login');
```

Login function

```
public function login(Request $request, User $user)
{
    
 $email = $request->input('email');
 $password = $request->input('password');

 $user = User::where('email', '=', $email)->first();
 if (!$user) {
    return response()->json(['success'=>false, 'message' => 'Login Fail, please check email']);
 }
 if (!Hash::check($password, $user->password)) {
    return response()->json(['success'=>false, 'message' => 'Login Fail, pls check password']);
 }
    return response()->json(['success'=>true,'message'=>'success', 'data' => $user]);
}
```

sorry for my english

Comment: Does `this.user.append("email", this.form.email);` throw any error in javascript?

Comment: there is not,the code runs without errors but the API looks like it's not being accessed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your laravel app always return `200` HTTP responses and this causes the `.then( ... )` in the frontend to always be executed.

Either in the `.then( ... )` your check the **success** value on the response that your Laravel has set, like this:

```
 this.user.append("email", this.form.email);
 this.user.append("password", this.form.password);
 this.axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login', this.user).then(response => {
   if (response.data.success === false) {
     // handle the error and stop the code with a return
     this.handleError();
     return;
   }
   localStorage.setItem("Name", response.data.first_name);
   this.$router.push('/userDashboard/Dashboard')
 });
```

OR, you can also in Laravel throw a `401` or `400` response to say the login failed which will throw an exeception in the frontend, that you can catch with `.then( ... ).catch( ... )`.

That is the most clean way, because no need to send `'success' => true` true anymore, since the HTTP code will be the source of truth with what happend.

```
public function login(Request $request, User $user)
{
    
 $email = $request->input('email');
 $password = $request->input('password');

 $user = User::where('email', '=', $email)->first();
 if (!$user || !Hash::check($password, $user->password)) {
    // never tell the person if it's email or password, always say it's one of both for security reasons
    return response(401)->json(['message' => 'Login Fail, please check email or password']);
 }

  return response()->json(['data' => $user]);
}
```

Last thing, I don't understand how `this.user.append("email", this.form.email);` works, because `this.user` seems to just be a simple object, so there isn't any `append` method on it.

So unless I'm missing something here, the best thing should just be to do:

```
const user = {
  email: this.form.email,
  password: this.form.password
}

// OR, make a copy
const user = { ...this.form }

// then send the user var to axios
this.axios.post('your url', user).then( ... )
```

Comment: Hi,thank you for your quick respons the code its working now!! thanks a lot man,you are my lifesafer.XD

Comment: Glad I could help, please note my answer as resolved for the next people that come accros this question.